# HTML form method post does not work with multiple submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

HTML form method post does not work with multiple submit

I have the following

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">

<select name="select_data">
<option value="1000">Account Demo 1</option>
<option value="1035">Account Demo 2</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" onclick="sendForm('<?php echo $domainURL;?>page_1')" form="myForm" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Page 1">

<input type="submit" onclick="sendForm('<?php echo $domainURL;?>page_2')" form="myForm" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Page 2">
```

```
<script>
    function sendForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('myForm').action = action;
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

I did some testing, I change method to "get" and its work, but when I change method to "post" , it not able send anything.

I tried with

```
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
```

Get was able to retrieve the send value on a select option tag.
Same code, but post doesn't send through

I tried to do post

```
if action="" , its work fine
but if action="http://www.myowndomain.com/subpage/page/thepage.php" it does not work for post.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Javascript, use the `formaction` attribute:

```
<input type="submit" formaction="<?php echo $domainURL;?>page_1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Page 1">

<input type="submit" formaction="<?php echo $domainURL;?>page_2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Page 2">
```

THere's also no need for `form="myForm"` when the submit button is inside the `<form>` element.

Comment: I changed the code to your recommendation, but my method post still empty, get is working.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<input type="submit">` to `type="button"` I hope it will work.